# Por que é "vedes" e não "veis", e é "veríeis" e não "veríais"?

Tags: tempo-verbal, conjugações

Algumas conjugações da segunda pessoa do plural (*vós*) terminam em -des, como *pondes*, *tendes*, *vedes*. Inclusive o infinitivo pessoal («para vós fazerdes») e futuro do subjuntivo («se fizerdes»).  Ademais, algumas conjugações que, senão na segunda pessoal do plural, têm a, na segunda pessoal do plural, têm e: *veri**a***, *veri**a**s*, *verí**a**mos*, mas *verí**e**is*.

Por que não seguem a regra e são *teins*, *pões*/*põis*, *veis*, *fazêreis*, *fizéreis*, e *veríais*, *mataríais*, etc.?

Comment: Uau, um brasileiro a perguntar sobre a segunda pessoa do plural. Estudioso! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O **d** de *vós ve**d**es, pon**d**es*, etc. é hoje exceção, mas foi a regra no português  antigo. Só que, como explica a [Gramática Histórica da Lingua Portuguesa de Manuel Said Ali (1931, p. 139-40)](https://archive.org/details/SyntaxeDoPortuguezHistoricoEFormacaoDePalavras/page/n157/mode/2up?q=%22as%20desinencias%22), na maioria dos verbos esse d caiu. Exemplificando:

> latim           português antigo         português atual
> vós:       [amatis](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/verb:amare)                 amades                          amais
> vós:        [habetis](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/verb:habere)               havedes                         haveis
> vós:        [dormitis](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/verb:dormire)             dormides                       dormis

Explica Said Ali que esta desinência -*des* (e -*de* no imperativo) se usava ainda no século XIV. Ora o que anconteceu foi que nalguns verbos o d resistiu. São eles: *vós credes, ledes, vedes, ides, rides, pondes, tendes, vindes*.

Diz Said Ali que o n de *pondes, tendes* e *vindes* é um “vestígio da consoante nasal dos radicais primitivos”. Por exemplo, o latin *ponere* deu no português antigo *põer* (→*poer* → *pôr*): com a desinência -*des*, deu *pondes*; do mesmo modo (*tenere* → *tẽer* → *teer* → *ter*; *venire* → **vẽir* → *vĩir* → *vĩr* → *vir*; Said Ali, p. 171)

Estas exceções formam um padrão: são todos verbos monosilábicos (no infinitivo). E são quase todos os monosilábicos. Destes, só perderam o d o *dar* (*vós dais*) e o *ser* (*vós sois*), que ainda assim o manteve no imperativo (*sede*).

A desinência -***des*** ficou intacta de regra no futuro do subjuntivo/conjuntivo (*se vós fizer**des**, souber**des***) e no infinitivo pessoal (*para vós fazer**des**, saber**des***); na maior parte dos verbos os dois tempos são iguais (*se/para vós comer**des***). Said Ali diz que mesmo nestes tempos houve alguma tendência para o d cair (encontam-se exemplos na literatura), e que a sua manuntenção definitiva se deve “naturalmene á necessidade ou conveniência, no tratamento cerimonioso, de diversificar a 2.ª do plural da 2.ª do singular”. É que o d é a única diferença entra as duas: *souber**es**, souber**des**; saber**es**, saber**des***.

Ora este argumento aplica-se com igual força nalguns casos do presente do indicativo e imperativo. Caindo o d em *vós rides*, acabaria por dar *vós ris*, igual a *tu ris*. O mesmo com *vós pondes*: a pronúncia é /põdis/ ou, no português europeu atual, /põdɨs/; caindo o d ficaria igual a *pões*. Creio que o mesmo aconteceria com *vós tendes* e *tu tens*, pois *tens* é normalmente pronunciado como ditongo /tẽjs/ ou /tẽjʃ/. Nos outros casos, o plural e o singular não ficariam iguais, mas na maior parte deles ficariam muito parecidos: *veis* e *vês*, *creis* e *crês*. Se foi a necessidade de diferenciar suficientemente as formas que segurou o d também nestes casos, eu não sei. Onde não haveria necessidade nenhuma seria no *ides*: *is*, que não vingou mas está atestado, não se confundiria nunca com *vais*.

### Condicional/futuro do pretérito: *veríeis, havíeis*, etc.

Esta terminação -***íeis* é a regra**. Na língua atual. No português antigo, a terminação era -*íades*; com a queda do d, as vogais alteraram-se e passaram a -*íeis*.

Said Ali (p. 156) explica que nas línguas românicas o futuro simples do latim foi substituído por uma aglutinação do infinitivo ao presente do indicativo ne *haver* na sua forma contraída (sem o *av*): *comerei* = *comer* + *hei*, *comeremos* = *comer* + *hemos* de *havemos*. Do mesmo modo, o condicional (terminologia em Portugal) ou futuro do pretérito (Brasil) formou-se do infinitivo acrescido do imperfeito do indicativo de *haver* também na sua forma contraída: *comeria* = *comer* + *hia* de *havia*. Ora no português antigo o imperfeito do pretérito de *haver* era *havíades*, que deu no pretérito do futuro formas como *comeríades, beberíades*, etc. Com a queda do d, passaram a *comeríeis, beberíeis*, etc. Exceções, mas não nas terminações, que são sempre as mesmas, são so verbos *dizer, fazer* e *trazer* (no passado, também *jazer*), que perdem o -*ze*: *eu farei, vós fareis, eu faria, vós faríeis*.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Interessante que havia "ris" e "is" na segunda pessoa do plural, e também que "vedes", "credes", "ledes" e "rides" vieram de "v**ee**r", "cr**ee**r", "l**ee**r" e "r**ii**r". O verbo "ir" já é mais complexo. Obrigado de novo.

Comment: @Schilive, sempre às ordens. No tempo de *veer* tinhas *veedes*. Basicamente, no latim era *videre, vos videtis* → *veer, veedes* (caiu o d e o t passou a d) → *ver, vedes*; do mesmo modo *ridere, vos ridetis* → *riir, riides* → *rir, rides*, etc. A literatura medieval está cheia de *veedes, creedes*; só encontrei um *riides*; também há *seedes*, muito menos comum que *sodes* (→ *sois*).

Comment: Acho interessante que em galego, a língua falada na Galiza (no Noroeste da Península Ibérica), esses tempos continuam a ser como no português antigo em quase todos os verbos, sem tirar o "d".

Comment: @O'Bieito, não sabia. Como ficou nos verbos em que o d caiu? Isto no português foi. curioso.  Passar o t intervocálico a d foi comum. Cair o d intervocálico latino também aconteceu (*sair, cair, ver, crer*). Mas acontecer um coisa em cima da outra, passar o t a d, e depois esse d cair, acho que só mesmo nas terminações verbais.

Comment: Pois @Jacinto, acho que na maioria dos verbos nos que posso pensar é mesmo assim, vedes, credes, ledes, rides...  sodes, tedes, podedes, queredes, estades, amades, ides, mirades... Mas na verdade nao conheço a evoluiçao dos mesmos...

Comment: @O'Bieito e Jacinto. Podeis ver a conjugação no Wiktionary, como https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ver#Galician ou https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crer#Galician. Imagino que a evolução de "vedes" tenha sido videtis (latim) > veedes (g.-p.) > vedes (g.-p.), tanto que *vedes* aparece em textos antigos considerados em galego-português, no século XII; "credes" aparece em 1 texto do século XV, mas "creedes" aparece apenas em oito, então é possível "credes" já ter existido antes. Ou seja, aparentemente, o galego parou de evoluir em relação à segunda pessoa do plural e o português continuou, tirando dd.

Answer (score 0):

**"** Porque não seguem a regra? **"**
**Existe uma regra a respeito?**

Vejamos alguns verbos da segunda conjugação no futuro do pretérito:

- veria, verias, veria, veríamos, **veríeis**, veriam
- poderia, poderias, poderia, poderíamos, **poderíeis**, poderiam
- reveria, reverias, reveria, reveríamos, **reveríeis**, reveriam
- leria, lerias, leria, leríamos, **leríeis**, leriam
- precaveria, precaverias, precaveria, precaveríamos, **precaveríeis**, precaveriam
- teceria, tecerias, teceria, teceríamos, **teceríeis**, teceriam
- regeria, regerias, regeria, regeríamos, **regeríeis**, regeriam

Não parece haver uma regra onde a segunda pessoa do plural teria a terminação "ais"

**A regra existente é que** pelo verbo *ver*, conjugamos seus derivados *antever, entrever, prever e rever*; mas não *prover* e *precaver*.

Comment: Centaurus, obrigado pela resposta. Eu acho que não entendeste a minha pergunta. Eu não sei como explicar aqui no comentário, então, ... Obrigado!

Comment: @Schilive   Por favor, explique.  A sua pergunta é "porque não seguem a regra?".  Foi a partir daí que elaborei minha resposta.

Comment: Centaurus, eu quis perguntar o motivo da irregularidade aparente; p.ex.: por que "vejo" e não "vo"? A melhor resposta seria algo como "video" → "vidyo" → "vedjo" → "vejo". Ou seja, um motivo etimológico para isso. Novamente, obrigado pela resposta.